# Android AccessibilityNodeInfo get image content

Tags: android, accessibility

If AccessibilityNodeInfo.getClassName() invocation return "android.widget.ImageView", is it possible to get the image content (byte array, bitmap or drawable) from the AccessibilityNodeInfo object?

Note: The viewIdResourceName of the said AccessibilityNodeInfo is null. I have no way to identify the image except performing a checksum on image content.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if AccessinbilityNodeInfo allows you to get the imageView, but have you considered using [getItemCount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityRecord.html#getItemCount()) to get a list of indexes for your imageViews and attaching them to each imageView using setTag(). You could iterate through the list and get the object needed once the AccessibilityEvent is fired.

Comment: Hi sterling, I able to to to identify and get all the ImageView related node with AccessibilityNodeInfo.getChild(i) but I not able to get the reference of ImageView from the identified node.

Comment: I have modified my question as I think It was quite misleading.

Answer (score 0):

AccessibilityNodeInfo.getClassName() returns only a CharSequence i.e. String name. You do not get reference to the object of that type, so you can not extract data.